# Simple multiple child exec'd fork segfaulting when trying to read from stdout of child

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, exec, fork, pipe

I set up a simple fork example to fork and exec 2 children then read their output via pipes however I have a segfault (occuring at close(piping[i][1]);) and cannot find out why. See Code Below:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int reader(int *piping[]) {
    char readstring[50];
    char readstring2[50];
    FILE *outPut;
    FILE *outPut2;
    outPut = fdopen(piping[0][0], "r");
    outPut2 = fdopen(piping[1][0], "r");
    fgets(readstring, sizeof(readstring), outPut);
    fgets(readstring2, sizeof(readstring2), outPut2);
    printf("%s\n", readstring);
    printf("%s\n", readstring2);
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int j;
    int pid;
    int **piping = malloc(sizeof(int*) *2);
    for(i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        piping[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) *2); 
    }   
    for(j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
        pipe(piping[j]);
        if((pid = fork()) == -1)   
            fprintf(stderr, "error reading pipe\n");
            exit(1);
        } else if(pid == 0) {
            //child
            //close read pipes dup2 write pipes to stdout
            //then close old write pipes
            close(piping[j][0]);
            if(dup2(piping[j][1], 1) == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "error dup2");
                exit(2);
            }
            close(piping[j][0]);
            close(1);
            if(execlp("./playex", "playex", NULL)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "exec error\n");
            }
        } else {
            //parent
            close(piping[j][1]);
        }
    }
    reader(piping);
}
```

Above is the main function that pipes and execs then should go to read, below I have the basic program it runs.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    fprintf(stdout, "go\n");
}
```

I've tried to fix the segfault with no luck, please help with locating and fixing the issue.

Comment: Use a debugger.  Figure out where the segfault is.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include that it segfaults at close(piping[i][1]) thats what i cannot figure out. Cause by all accounts i need to close the write side of parent.

Comment: malloc() is used so that one pipe will be at piping[0] and one at piping[1], thas where my filedes are.(Im using it because Ill need to adapt this to larger scale via arguments so i can sub them in for the size). Should I not be?

Comment: The only time `execlp()` returns is when it fails, so you really don't need to test its return value.  You should, however, exit after reporting the error message.  However, none of that is going to cause the segmentation fault.

Comment: Why do you have `close(1);` before the `execlp()` — that carefully closes the standard output that you've just set up to write to the pipe.  That is going to cause some trouble.  You don't check the `fgets()` calls worked — or that the `fdopen()` calls worked — so you don't know whether is is safe to use the file streams or the buffers you (may or may not) have read. Yu have 4 unnecessary headers in your minimal program that prints `go`.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem was (before you edited the question to hide what it originally showed) that you were writing outside the bounds of your array of pipes:

```
for(i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    piping[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) *2); 
}   
for(j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
    pipe(piping[i]);
```

You were indexing the second loop on `j`, not `i`, so you were using `piping[2]` which is not allocated.  Rinse and repeat.

You could have avoided the error by removing the current definitions of `i` and `j` and using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    piping[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) *2); 
}   
for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
    pipe(piping[i]);
```

Now `i` would be undefined in the second loop.

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot i noticed a moment ago and feel like an idiot now.

Comment: Welcome to the club; we all feel like idiots sometimes (but it tends to happen a bit more when you're starting than after you've been programming for some years).